# How to export report to .CSV in SSRS?

Tags: csv, reporting-services

I have a report I made using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) and I would like to export the results in .CSV format.

Currently, I only have PDF, Excel and TIFF file as the options. How do I export it to a .csv format?

I would like to add a subscription to it and using 'Windows File Share', I would like it to save the results as a .CSV file on our network.

I'm not sure how to check the version of SSRS I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output options available to you are in the reportserver config XML file.

Ensure you back up the file before you play with it.. You might already have the necessary code in the config file but CSV output might simply be turned off.

The location of this is on the report server.. usually

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRSXXXX.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer
```

File name : - `rsreportserver.config`

Look for the entry `<Extension Name="CSV..... Visible="false"/>`

Just remove the `Visible = "False"`

More than likely that is the scenario you have. But if it isn't there, you need an entry in there similar to the following

```
<Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
                <Configuration>
                    <DeviceInfo>
                        <ExcelMode>False</ExcelMode>
                    </DeviceInfo>
                </Configuration>
            </Extension>
```

Not sure if you need to restart services after this.. but give it a go.

**ENSURE YOU BACKUP YOUR CONFIG FILE** **before** you play with it.

Getting things wrong will stop reporting services from working all together!

Comment: Would this '<ExcelMode>False</ExcelMode>' turn off exporting to Excel ?

Comment: Along with csv, a few other options were commented out by default. The ones needed were then  uncommented and I am now able to export to .csv format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Excel mode tries to ensure data is exported in a way excel can format each column in the appropriate data type and not all text